# Eglibc cannot compile suffix of object files while trying to cross compile

Tags: linux, compiling, glibc, lfs, cross-compilation

I'm currently making my way through Trac's CLFS book. 
When trying to configure the 32-bit version of EGLIBC-2.15, using the options:

> ```
> BUILD_CC="gcc" CC="${CLFS_TARGET}-gcc ${BUILD32}" \
> AR="${CLFS_TARGET}-ar" RANLIB="${CLFS_TARGET}-ranlib" \
> CFLAGS="-march=$(cut -d- -f1 <<< $CLFS_TARGET32) -mtune=generic -g -O2" \
> ../eglibc-2.15/configure --prefix=/tools \
> --host=${CLFS_TARGET32} --build=${CLFS_HOST} \
> --disable-profile --enable-add-ons \
> --with-tls --enable-kernel=2.6.0 --with-__thread \
> --with-binutils=/cross-tools/bin --with-headers=/tools/include \
> --cache-file=config.cache
> ```

I get the following output:

```
configure: loading cache config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-cross-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/eglibc-build':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

The config.log reads:

```
configure:1879: loading cache config.cache
configure:2029: checking build system type
configure:2047: result: x86_64-cross-linux-gnuconfigure: loading cache config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-cross-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/eglibc-build':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
configure:2069: checking host system type
configure:2084: result: i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2115: checking for i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:2142: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32
configure:2414: checking for C compiler version
configure:2422: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32 --version >&5
../eglibc-2.15/configure: line 2424: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
configure:2426: $? = 127
configure:2433: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32 -v >&5
../eglibc-2.15/configure: line 2435: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
configure:2437: $? = 127
configure:2444: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32 -V >&5
../eglibc-2.15/configure: line 2446: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
configure:2448: $? = 127
configure:2452: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2478: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -m32 -c -march=i686 -mtune=generic -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
../eglibc-2.15/configure: line 2480: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
configure:2482: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2496: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/eglibc-build':
configure:2499: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Trying to compile with the CC parameter set to just "gcc $BUILD32" gets me much further, although it does complain about the loss of a triplet. Doing so, however, gives me:

```
checking for __builtin_expect... no
configure: error: support for __builtin_expect needed
```

I'm lost at this point, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The path to arm7..-gcc should be entered manually; it does not recognize `${CLFS_TARGET}-gcc`. Instead, use:

```
CC="/mnt/clfs/cross-tools/bin/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```